# Inconsistency of scoping between "type ...and " and "let ...and " in Ocaml

Tags: types, ocaml, scoping, let

I wonder why in OCaml, `let ... and` does not have the same kind of scoping as `type ... and`.

The following one is OK, `t2` is in the same scope as `t1`:

```
# type t1 = t2 
and t2 = int;;
```

This following one is wrong, `v2` is not in scope:

```
# let v1 = v2
and v2 = 3;;

  Characters 9-11:
  let v1 = v2
           ^^

Error: Unbound value v2
```

Even `let rec` does not work:

```
# let rec v1 = v2
and v2 = 3;;

  Characters 13-15:
  let rec v1 = v2
               ^^
Error: This kind of expression is not allowed as right-hand side of `let rec'
```

Why this inconsistency of scoping between  `type... and` and `let...and`?

Answer (score 9):

Types are implicitly recursive. If you want to have the same effect with "let", use "let rec .. and".

In an ideal language, binding forms where that makes sense should have two versions, one recursive and one non-recursive. That's the case for `let` in Caml, you have `let` and `let rec`. There is no accessible form of non-recursive type binding; it need not be the default, even `type nonrec ...` would do. This is a defect of the Caml syntax; bad consequences of the inability of non-recursive type definition are given [in this blog post](https://blogs.janestreet.com/ocaml-annoyance-23-type-declarations-are-implicitly-recursive/) for example.

Regarding your second example, this is not about scoping, but the validity of certain recursive definitions and not others. This is an entirely orthogonal concern (see the [ocaml manual](http://caml.inria.fr/pub/docs/manual-ocaml/manual021.html#toc70) for which recursive definitions are valid), and `let rec` does exactly what you want here, scoping-wise.

Comment: Types are implicitly *equirecursive*.  To get *isorecursive* types, you need to use the `-rectypes` flag on the compiler.  The perceived inconsistency here is just a wart in the syntax, and it's not really worth getting bent out of shape about it.  There just isn't a real need for a `type nonrec... and...` construct in the language like there is for the `let... and... in...` construct.

Comment: @james: I think you got it wrong, `-rectypes` enables equirecursivity (equality between a name and its unfolding) while standard algebraic data types are isorecursives (isomorphism, mediated by the constructor, between the name and its unfolding). This has *nothing* to do with the scoping question though (is this name available in scope ?). On the `nonrec` matter, have you read the blog post I linked to, which demonstrates real annoyance caused by forcefully-recursive type definitions?

Comment: For posterity: `type nonrec` is now a thing.